# Using SWReveal in multiple views

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWReveal in my main view, it works perfectly, but when I try to connect SWReveal to another view controller it won't work.

I mean I want to show SWReveal menu in any view contoller that I want, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change front view of swreveal by pushing

```
self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(newFrontViewController, animated: true)
```

After that add target to menu button

```
button.addTarget( self.revealViewController(), action:"revealToggle:" , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```